# How to detect Windows Logon event?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, delphi, winapi

How do you detect Windows logon event?

And how do you initiate a user logon from a Windows service?

I'm trying to write a piece of code that will detect logon events and log another one automatically.

Answer (score 2):

> How do you detect Windows logon event?

If any mechanism exists it is likely to be in WMI. There are a number of WMI classes. Notably `Win32_LogonSession`; which is related to `Win32_Account` via `Win32_LoggedonUser`). If creation events are supported for `Win32_LogonSession` then that would be a very effective method.

> And how do you initiate a user logon from a Windows service?

The `LogonUser` API allows creating a new user token, you can then use that token for threads or processes. Using `CreateProcessWithLogonW` (and similar) allows the user name and password to be created to create a process under a different account (essentially `LogonUser` plus `CreateProcessWithTokenW`).

Answer (score 2):

If you are developing for Windows 2000/XP you can create a Winlogon Notification Package using the JWA libraries and Delphi. They've made it extremely easy:

http://blog.delphi-jedi.net/2008/05/27/winlogon-notification-package/

This also allows you to put a form on the CTRL+ALT+DEL screen if you'd like as well. That form is running under the SYSTEM profile.

Answer (score 1):

You can detect a user logon by for example monitoring the event log. You can also start a process with a specific user, as Richard explained.

However, it sounds like you are trying so do something else, that is to swap the logon identity of the logged on user. This I do not think is possible.

Answer (score 1):

[WTSRegisterSessionNotification()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383841%28VS.85%29.aspx) or a [Winlogon Notification Package](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374783%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Winlogon Notification Package are removed from Vista.

Use WTSRegisterSessionNotification or [System Event Notification Service (SENS)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa377589%28VS.85%29.aspx). 
However, you cannot logon a user interactively s.t. the logon dialog is removed and the user desktop is shown instead. This is done by winlogon using some registry keys. LogonUser just gives you a token that you can use to impersonate a user.